# How to ng-repeat in one place?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following array `[{'id' : 0, 'name' : 'first'}, {'id' : 1, 'name' : 'second'}]`

```
<li ng-repeat="x in array"><strong>Names:</strong>{{x.name}}</li>
```

This code shows 2 li's.
But I want: Names: first, second

How can i achieve this?

Comment: `ng-repeat` repeats `html` elements, so maybe you can put it in a `span` if you want the entire array's name properties to show up in one `li` element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to repeat `<li>`, you must use `ng-repeat` in another tag within `li` tag:

```
<li>
  <strong>Names:</strong>
  <span ng-repeat="x in array">
    {{x.name}}
  </span>
</li>
```

Comment: Only way i think. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

put the ng repeat in a `span` tag inside `li` tag, instead of the `li` tag

`<li><strong>Names:</strong><span  ng-repeat="x in array">{{x.name}} </span>`

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.array = [{'id' : 0, 'name' : 'first'}, {'id' : 1, 'name' : 'second'}]

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <li><strong>Names:</strong><span  ng-repeat="x in array">{{x.name}} </span></li>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry was a typo. Already tried that. Instead of 2 different Names: I want just one. So Names: first  second

Comment: @Urban check the demo again